# CSS li inline & jquery sortable

Tags: php, html, css

having an issue with the jquery sortable code - it's not so much the jquery but how my list of images is showing. Prior to adding the sortable code it displayed the images in my wrapper in a grid like formation perfectly - now I have added a little style from the jquery it seems to have thrown it but im not sure why...

here is the Jquery style:

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
#sortable li {float: left; }
</style>
```

Here is my list of images that worked perfectly ok before:

```
<div id="images">
    <hr style="margin-top: 10px" />
    <ul id="sortable">
      <?php
        // get folio for user
        if(isset($_GET['userid'])) {
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM folio WHERE userid=\'' . $_GET['userid'] . '\' ORDER BY ord';
        }
        else {
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM folio WHERE userid=\'' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '\' ORDER BY ord';
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$result) {
            // error with MYSQL
            die('Failed to retrieve images! - ' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        // list images
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($numRows < 1) {
            echo '';
        }
        else {
            $filepath = 'uploads/folio/';
            while($imagerow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        ?>
      <li>
        <div class="outimgbox"> <a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" rel="gallery1" style="text-decoration: none;" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="profile_image_fancybox.php?imgid=<?php echo $imagerow['imgid']; ?>">
          <div id="mainwrapper">
            <div id="box-3" class="box"> <img class="uploads" src="<?php echo $filepath . $imagerow['filename']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imagerow['description']; ?>"/> <span class="caption fade-caption">
              <h3 ><?php echo $imagerow['title']; ?></h3>
              </span> </div>
          </div>
          </a> </div>
      </li>

      <!-- class outingbox -->
      <?php }} ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a CSS issue. More likely a PHP / HTML issue.

Comment: Show us the actual HTML that's in the browser before `sortable` runs, and then the HTML after `sortable` runs - the PHP code is just confusing the question. Have you inspected this in Firebug or the like?

Comment: open your dev console either firebug or any other and try turning off each style added and you will see what style produces this. I would say that it is probably #sortable li {float: left; } but it can be anything.

Comment: Hey guys yeah iv literally checked all through inspect element and nothing seems to be altering it....now the problem being that the sortable function does work without #sortable but not correctly - I have narrowed it down to the float: left which ensure that when you drag an image its taking the one you grab and not form tje top but it still takes the grid layout away

Comment: I figured out the issue...

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason:

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none;  }
#sortable li {float: left; }
</style>
```

This resolved the issue....